# Windows batch - detect console output

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to detect a server output running in a windows cmd prompt from another prompt and trigger something else. Is it possible?

Comment: ***wingardium leviosa**** did that work?

Comment: @AMR it's wingardium LeviOsa, not LevioSA

Comment: lmao.... touche'.....

Answer (score 1):

I think you *might* be able to accomplish this using a scripting/automation tool such as AutoIT.  While it was not completely solved, you can see the following link for some thoughts on the issue -
http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/64872-read-from-command-prompt-window/

You aren't really very clear on what you mean by "server output".  Is this an application you've written?  If so, instead of relying solely on parsing screen text why not also log to a flat file and another process could more easily read the contents found within.  Even better would be to log to a database where you would have fewer issues with file locking.

If the server application is not of your own creation, then does it write to a system events log?  This would still be easier to react to versus a console window.

Comment: If I use a file for log, how can I keep continuously checking this file for a string and once it appears trigger something?

Comment: You "monitoring program" would either have to loop, your you can created a scheduled task and have your monitoring program restarted repeated and when your trigger text is found if could perform your "something else" task.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a `Named Pipe` or a `"FIFO"` I have no idea how to do this in windows. I only did it once in college in linux. Heres the link, good luck

> A named pipe is a named, one-way or duplex pipe for communication
>   between the pipe server and one or more pipe clients.
>
> Any process can act as both a server and a client, making peer-to-peer
>   communication possible. As used here, the term pipe server refers to a
>   process that creates a named pipe, and the term pipe client refers to
>   a process that connects to an instance of a named pipe.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I you are lucky, this may work:

```
theOriginalProcess | theWatcherProcess.bat
```

And this is theWatcherProcess.bat

```
@echo off
rem Wait for output from theOriginalProcess and read it
set /P outputLine=
rem Trigger something else
echo Output from theOriginalProcess detected!
```

If this not works, then theWatcherProcess.bat requires that theOriginalProcess cooperate with it in some way. You may read a further description of this problem at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511246/batch-windows-execute-script-wait-for-request-and-input-the-answer/16514568#16514568), and the way to solve it at [this one](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3226&p=23970#p23970).

**EDIT**: I developed a new version of my asynchronous Tee.bat program that can be easily modified in order to solve your request. Look for it at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3226&p=26319#p26319).

Comment: @Sairam Sankaran: See the EDIT in my answer...